# Where can I find list of all the System Exceptions occurred in C#

Tags: c#, exception

Where can I find list of all the system exceptions occurred in C#?

I want to make an inventory of all the system exceptions occurred in C# so that I have the corresponding custom messages. Please help me out by mentioning any site or anything.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c18k6c59.aspx - Exception Class

Comment: Why not build-it-along? Every time new kind of exception occurs, you add that in your list. Only, if your system design permits.

Comment: You've received multiple answers but have failed to clarify why none of them are sufficient to your question. Please explain what you're doing, why you're doing it, and what your question is more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Dutts "Ctrl+Alt+E" solution, I parsed the list using ShareX's "Text Capture" tool. I have commented out ones that I was unable to find the assembly references to, but some listed are still deprecated. To find which ones are okay to use,

```
class Program {
    static void Foo<T>() { }
    static void Main() {
        Foo<  System.AccessViolationExample  >();
        // The rest of the list, with "Foo<  " prefixing and "  >();" suffixing each line. This can be done using Notepad++ macro recorder or a google search for "alphabetizer flap tv"
    }
}
```

I'm including the above code ONLY to include the pastebin link containing all the references, rather than listing them all here. StackOverflow requires code to accompany pastebin links.

https://pastebin.com/t19HRbck

Answer (score 0):

[This list by Brad Abrams](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/03/27/402801.aspx) is probably one of the closest you're going to get, but it is by no means 'all'; we have to draw the line somewhere and perhaps say *all* those in the BCL, as accounting for *every* exception would be a herculean task, and highly improbable even if not impossible to do - and, doing this is still an exercise in futility (why not add constant messages for exceptions that actually happen to you?).

Bear in mind that WinForms, WPF, WCF, and so one, each bring their own set of exceptions to the dinner party, too. Not to mention any third party stuff you might be working with, as, just in the previous cases, developers are free to follow the conventions for creating new exceptions to suit their needs.

Comment: Thanks for this information Thomas
. I understand that it will be a Gigantic task to do. But what i require is not all but some exceptions along with their System Error Numbers. I want them as I have to maintain an inventory with their custom(message in more understanding way) as I need to mail them afterwards..

Comment: Error numbers are largely irrelevant in .NET development and only exist to support legacy error management _a la_ MS native, where Win32 exceptions are wrapped in a managed class. In this case, MS native error codes have already been documented to death, and I see no other reason, as these, and any like them, certainly aren't the norm of .NET exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c18k6c59.aspx) is always a good place to start.

Note that (if I understand you correctly) your goal isn't very practical. While it certainly makes sense to create custom messages for exceptions in specific, limited scenarios, trying to do such a thing in a universal context is a little unusual.

Comment: Please help anybody.. I want the System generated messages. I am stuck here.. and cant proceed. I know every system generted errors cant pe presumed, but atleast i need some for my inventory. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can check the MSDN for [System.SystemException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.systemexception.aspx) (check the inheritance hierarchy for a large list of exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Exception classes can be custom defined for each specific purpose, so there's no complete master list of exceptions in C#.

In Visual Studio, hit Ctrl+Alt+E, and expand "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" for a list of the ones currently referenced by your project.